# elm how to set path to elm-stuf folder from main distribution

Tags: environment, elm

I can start **elm-make** **elm-reactor** and so on from any place because I included the path to Elm_Platform binaries into my **$PATH** env variable

But I still have to copy all libs (elm-stuff folder) for any project, anytime when I started it in some new place

i read installation stuff from elm-lang.org, but did not find the anwser

do u know how it can be resolved?

tnx

Comment: For us to be able to help you out we need to know in more precise manner what the problem you're experiencing is. Can't really tell from the question what you are trying to do or what you think the expected outcome would be.

Comment: I am sorry , I just started using this resorse /// if I create new project and connected to Internet, when all is good, but if I offline when elm tells me that it could't get files /// I can copy them by hand (so I do it now) but maybe some way do it once and point out to Elm to take files from this place /// sorry agn

Comment: Yeah, ok. You're right. I think I understand what you mean. If you're building or creating a project from scratch then you need Internet access to download any package dependencies. I don't think there is a way in Elm to circumvent that behaviour but if you're serious about it maybe you could setup a local proxy or something like that. But it sure feels like going through a lot of trouble... If you really have limited Internet access most of the time perhaps putting a carefully selected set of precompiled elm-stuff folders on a USB-stick could work. Sorry for not providing a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

`elm-stuff` is created or updated whenever you compile, no need to copy it around.

Comment: yes, in case you connected to inet then all stuff will be downloaded, but if you offline you should copy all files (which you have already but in other project folder) by hand /// I suppose what maybe there is somekinde of global directory (as /usr/lib in nix) in elm infrastructure

Comment: Yes, if you have no internet then you'll need to copy elm-stuff around at present to satisfy your dependencies. You didn't mention that constraint! There's an issue on the elm-package repo regarding using local git repos for dependencies, and Evan brings up being able to use a local version of package.elm-lang.org for use cases where sharing code isn't an option, both would no doubt help you, so you might want to chip in with your thoughts. https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-package/issues/87#issuecomment-69151069